# Nested Unless tags break Liquid/Jekyll

Tags: collections, jekyll, github-pages, liquid, unless

I've been working with generating some JSON data from liquid tags, it seems that excluding the last comma in this JSON data is not happening when nesting 'unless' tags.

*Please see answer below, this initial issue and question was not the problem.*

```html
<script id="suggest-json" type="application/json">
[
    {%- for item in site[page.collection] -%}
    {%- unless item.url == page.url -%}

    {% assign images = item.media | where: "type", "image" %}
    {% assign image = images.first %}
    {
        "url": "{{site.baseurl}}{{ item.url }}",
        "title": "{{ item.title }}",
        "subject": "{{ item.game }}",
        "image": "{{ image.thumbnail }}",
        "alt": "{{ image.thumbnail_alt }}"
    } {%- unless forloop.last -%},{%- endunless -%}

    {%- endunless -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
]
</script>
```

Undesired Output (The last comma is invalidating the Json):

```json
[
    
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/low-life/",
        "title": "Low-Life",
        "subject": "Final Verdikt: Source",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    },
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/prospekt/",
        "title": "Prospekt",
        "subject": "Final Verdikt: Source",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    },    
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/station/",
        "title": "Station",
        "subject": "Half-Life 2: Opposition",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    },
    
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/dredge/",
        "title": "Dredge",
        "subject": "Firearms: Source",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    },   
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/gravitas/",
        "title": "Gravitas",
        "subject": "Firearms: Source",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    }, 
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/navarro/",
        "title": "Navarro",
        "subject": "Firearms: Source",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    },
    {
        "url": "/portfolio/levels/deadlock/",
        "title": "Deadlock",
        "subject": "Half-Life 2: Opposition",
        "image": "https://picsum.photos/445/296?random=1",
        "alt": "Image 1"
    },]
```

I've tried If statements, assigning booleans for isLast index, spacing and other formatting but nothing works...

## Answer

The main issue here was separating my array into a new suggestions array minus the filtered item, which makes `forloop.last` actually happen. The other way was just ignoring the filtered item, but considering it still part of the array, which is why `forloop.last` was never `true`.

I also use `{% raw %}` tag to escape the JSON brackets for safe measure. I thought this might be causing Jekyll to try and process them as a tag, leading to an error with no actual error output in the `--verbose` build logs. *Although I think the main culprit was the need to create a separate array to loop through.*

```html
{% assign suggestions = "" | split: ',' %}
{%- for item in site[page.collection] -%}
{%- unless item.url == page.url -%}
{% assign suggestions = suggestions | push: item %}
{%- endunless -%}
{%- endfor -%}
<script id="suggest-json" type="application/json">
[
{%- for item in suggestions -%}
    {% assign images = item.media | where: "type", "image" %}
    {% assign image = images.first %}
    {% raw %}
    {
    {% endraw %}
        "url": "{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}",
        "title": {{ item.title | jsonify }},
        "subject": {{ item.game | jsonify }},
        "image": {{ image.thumbnail | jsonify }},
        "alt": {{ image.thumbnail_alt | jsonify }}
    {% raw %}
    }
    {% endraw %}
    {%- unless forloop.last -%},{%- endunless -%}
{%- endfor -%}
]
</script>
```